# Must try wines in Frankfurt region

Tags: recommendations, wine, germany

Some regions around Frankfurt are famous for their wines. When I was in Frankfurt last time, I tried their Apple wine and simply loved it. This time, I will be in Frankfurt for a longer period and would like to try some more of their famous wines. I have not tried any special wines before and most probably will not spend a lot on wines. So please suggest something for a beginner within budget that is available in Frankfurt main city area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would spend your limited time and money just tasting wines from one region.  **Nahe** is a smaller wine region just west of Frankfurt, and I've found the wines there to be good quality, with individual charm (in other words, without the sense that they are mass-produced).  [More info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahe_(wine_region))

By all means, talk to locals: the people you're visiting, the clerk in your hotel.  That's almost always a great way to discover something.

Comment: Tasting to a pattern or strategy is a great idea.  An alternative to tasting from a single region is to taste a single varietal (Riesling or Silvaner or Grüner Veltliner) from different makers or regions.  The suggestion to seek out local recommendations is excellent.  Best of all is to bring a friend and talk about what you're tasting.